# Different row for each unit

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a nested array list and I would like to get a different table row for every `unit`.

JSON:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "units":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "name":"Test 1",
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "name":"Test 2"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

So `Test 1` and `Test 2` should be in different table rows.

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users">
    <td><p ng-repeat="unit in user.units">{{unit.name}}</p></td>
</tr>
```

The above code works but I am getting `unit` names in the same row.

I tried:

```
<tr ng-repeat="unit in users.units">
    <td>{{unit.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

But that doesn't work. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Is the extra [ ] opening brackets required?

Comment: There's no object called `users.units`, so it can't find your data. That's why that doesn't work.

Comment: @HankScorpio so is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Well as a general rule with all programming languages: Don't target data that doesn't exist.
Also, see the answer posted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that won't require any changes to your data, though it may not be the cleanest solution. The other option (which I'm not going to write up) is to modify your data and flatten the data down to a single array or object containing all the units.

I'm going to make an assumption that you want your DOM (including the `<table>`) to ideally look like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Test 1</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Test 2</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The problem here is there isn't anything that represents the "users" part of that first ng-repeat (2 ng-repeats are needed for this data structure). As far as I'm aware it's not possible to start an ng-repeat without also creating a DOM element (at least a temporary one), so we can create some valid html (`<caption>`s in this case) and have angular exclude it using a one-time binding ng-if.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <table>
        <!-- The ng-if here will remove the <caption> from the end result. It's just a placeholder for the users repeater. -->
        <caption ng-repeat-start="user in users" ng-if="::false"></caption>
        <tr ng-repeat="unit in user.units">
            <td><p>{{unit.name}}</p></td>
        </tr>
        <caption ng-repeat-end ng-if="::false"></caption>
    </table>
</div>
```